# Android: How to get the direction the device are currently facing towards similar to Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, sensors

I am currently using Location Service to get the location of the user as well as get the address through Geocoder.

I stored those data for later display. At the same time, i want to save the direction they are facing towards when the application taken their location.

Does google map use the compass API to handle it when travelling or is there any other android library which i have missed.

I am doubting it used the Compass Api coz my phone don't have the sensor when I tried to install the Compass app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Positions Sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position#java):

> ```
> public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
>
>     private SensorManager sensorManager;
>     private final float[] accelerometerReading = new float[3];
>     private final float[] magnetometerReading = new float[3];
>
>     private final float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
>     private final float[] orientationAngles = new float[3];
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.main);
>         sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
>         // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
>         // You must implement this callback in your code.
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onResume() {
>         super.onResume();
>
>         // Get updates from the accelerometer and magnetometer at a constant rate.
>         // To make batch operations more efficient and reduce power consumption,
>         // provide support for delaying updates to the application.
>         //
>         // In this example, the sensor reporting delay is small enough such that
>         // the application receives an update before the system checks the sensor
>         // readings again.
>         Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
>         if (accelerometer != null) {
>             sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
>                 SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
>         }
>         Sensor magneticField = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
>         if (magneticField != null) {
>             sensorManager.registerListener(this, magneticField,
>                 SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPause() {
>         super.onPause();
>
>         // Don't receive any more updates from either sensor.
>         sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
>     }
>
>     // Get readings from accelerometer and magnetometer. To simplify calculations,
>     // consider storing these readings as unit vectors.
>     @Override
>     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
>         if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
>           System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, accelerometerReading,
>               0, accelerometerReading.length);
>         } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
>             System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magnetometerReading,
>                 0, magnetometerReading.length);
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Compute the three orientation angles based on the most recent readings from
>     // the device's accelerometer and magnetometer.
>     public void updateOrientationAngles() {
>         // Update rotation matrix, which is needed to update orientation angles.
>         SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null,
>             accelerometerReading, magnetometerReading);
>
>         // "rotationMatrix" now has up-to-date information.
>
>         SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationAngles);
>
>         // "orientationAngles" now has up-to-date information.
>     }
> }
> ```

Both Accelerometer (7.3.1.) and Magnetometer (7.3.2.) are "STRONGLY RECOMMENDED" in [Android Compatibility Definition](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#7_3_sensors) and highly likely present in your device.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I realized my phone don't have the Magnetometer. My device only have Accelerometer, proximity sensors.

Comment: @LittleFunny You can use Gyroscope for detect North direction ([link1](https://www.sensorsportal.com/HTML/DIGEST/september_2014/Vol_178/P_2346.pdf), [link2](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1110826/FULLTEXT01.pdf) but it needs some special condition like device rotation).

Comment: @LittleFunny Or you can provide UI for [empiric estimate of North direction](https://www.jackravenbushcraft.co.uk/find-north-with-your-watch/): it can be determined by local time and direction to the Sun.